# ActionBarSherlock wrong tabs position on android 2.2.2

Tags: android, tabs, position, actionbarsherlock

I'm having serious problems getting tabs in actionbarsherlock below main action bar tabs to work in an app that runs from Android 2.2 up and looks like Android 4. (see link)

[Tabs position](http://test4.net-informatika.com/20121017_104745.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the official Demos app of ActionBar Sherlock? (https://github.com/downloads/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/ActionBarSherlock-Sample-Demos-4.2.0.apk) It should contain a demo for the actionbar with Tabs.

If that works on Android 2.2 then you know the problem is in your code and you can check the Demos source code to see what you are doing differently (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples).

Comment: Tried the demo and the behaviour is the same, the tabs get rendered between the Title and the Action Items, instead of them being below these two. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's usual behavior of action bar (actionbarsherlock just simulate it). Use

```
ActionBar act = getSupportActionBar();
act.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mytab_base_t));
```

to avoid white color in top bar (this option you can't access from any theme item yet). You can also monitor action bar height to change custom view of tabs on-fly, but you can't change action bar behavior, forget it. Otherwise please use PagerTitleStrip against action bar tabs.

Comment: On samsung S1 (android 2.3) and all other devices action bar looks like on the picture [Tabs position][1]
  [1]: http://test4.net-informatika.com/bar.png I need action bar like this